# No branches in SourceTree?

Tags: git, repository, push, branch, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a project on my PC, I want to host it on BitBucket as a Git repo. I've been using SourceTree to manage an existing project with other contributors, so I know the basics about modifying a repository, but I haven't made my own one before.

What I've done so far was make a brand new repo on BitBucket, then I went in SourceTree and made a new one in there. I added a remote called `origin` using the URL BitBucket gave me, but when I try to push I see this:

[image: No branch]

Usually I'm supposed to choose which branches to push, but here I don't see any. Apparently I'm on `master` though, which it shows in the left pane.

Basically, I'm confused. Can anyone explain what's going on or what I'm supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to create at least one commit into your local branch before trying to push.

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I didn't try that. The command-line instructions didn't mention this (it just said to push), but this completely solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I faced the same problem the first time a created a repo. Now I know GIT better it seems obvious, but for a beginner it's not.

Answer (score 21):

**Tools -> Options -> Git -> Push branches**
Change from 'simple' to 'matching'

Comment: So far it's the lone solution that worked. I tried to upgrade Sourcetree, and then git, and then create a local branch, but it didn't help.

Comment: I did several commit and pushes. Suddenly there were no branches to push to.  your solution worked, thanks

Comment: I had often troubles when trying to push a branch when a remote branch was linked to multiple local ones. I didn't know that setting.
I just had to select "Upstream" instead of "Matching" in my context. Thanks Andrei.

Answer (score 10):

This works for me:
Goto Tools->Options->Git
and select "Embedded".

[image: Screenshot of Git tabn in source tree]

Comment: Thank you, switching to embedded and updating helped. I was not aware, that the System GIT was  used.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. I was helped by removing git, and installing it again via SourceTree

Comment: This resolved the issue for me. Sourcetree seemed to have trouble with my old, non-embedded git installation.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue after updating SourceTree to version 3.2.6. Updating SourceTree did not update the embedded git client automatically.

Updating the git client manually via Tools > Options > Git > Update embedded solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed the issue by using fetch option .It fetches all the branches and then i have set the Tools > Options > Git > push branches to simple.

It starts working fine now

Answer (score 0):

This bug appeared after updating Sourcetree to v 3.2.6.3544
while using System Git v 2.12.0

Updating System Git to v 2.24.0 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated and it has not worked for me. I have switched to System and back to Embedded and this has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have removed the origin branch. In the terminal, run command
"git branch --unset-upstream"
Then restart SourceTree and try to push.